# Containters not aligning properly in Bootstrap project

Tags: html, css

This is a continuation of a small project I started on over the weekend (I raised a query re H1 header size).  I've got this as far as I want to take it at this stage (simple to-do list - non-functional at the moment).  I added a navbar and designed an imported my own logo (in the menu bar and at the bottom of the screen).  I've included the code from a codepen but for some reason (not sure at the moment) it hasn't pulled through the background colour and logo PNG hence why I've included a screenshot too.

However, the issue is that I cannot locate where I'm going wrong with regard to the containers not lining up: you can see the first two containers (with one row each - with the ADD rect which I'm going to change to a box and the 'You have '3' complete tasks:" rect box) then the five containers/rows below that are offset from those above.

The code for the "container-row-col" is (as far as I can tell) the same, but would placing all these rows in one container (containing all the 7 rows plus their columns) make a difference?
Maybe the media queries need to be looked at?

```
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-8 col-md-6 white-rect mr-4 mb-2 ">|.............................................
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 white-rect center-block">ADD</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here's a snippet of the container-row-col code with a codepen link below. I can only apologise for the amount of commenting out I've done...part of my learning process I guess.

Many thanks.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/somapop/pen/QWWjeJz)

[Screen Shot of Full Page as it appears in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdlU8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many nested `containers`. Just put all your `.row`s into one parent `.container` or add some style to the nested `.container`s witch will remove the extra `padding`. Something like this:

```css
.container .container {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks Maxim...was beginning to suspect that. I'd copied each container (amending the odd detail) and obviously copied the container in each one too. I'll place them all under one container (as they are effectively bunched together). I haven't actually got a reference to container (.container) in CSS so I'll do that.  BTW - can I then call that .container from the <div (so I can add further styling to the container?).  I"ll try and work that bit out.  Also noticed the buttons are different sizes (depending on text length). Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Of course you can add selector `.container` to your css file.. just check that it loads after the Bootstrap's css so it could override the bootstrap's style. And of course you can add your own classes too... If you want your buttons to be of the same width you could add to your css this: `button { min-width: 50px }` .. or whatever size you would like.. use `min-widht` so you wont brake buttons with a very long text..

Comment: Excellent - thanks again. I actually tried that .container .container padding code and it worked immediately (containers lined up perfectly) but I'll place all the rows into one parent as it's a neater solution.  I'll try that button code in CSS too.  At this stage I'm trying to work out how much Boostrap can be configured/amended - seems like I'm not using a great deal of the standard 'theme' so far.  Enjoying it though. Thanks once again!

Comment: Apologies - I forgot to ask  - the buttons (as you can see) are off centre to the white rectangle. I tried to add a span solution, but that seemed more fitting for text rather than buttons.  They're off centre to the white rectangle on the rows. This was the code: ```<span class="centered">TEXT</span>```.  Btw - I've added the .button code into CSS butit hasn't made a difference - do I need to call it differently from HTML (as .button rather than button)?

Comment: EDIT  - this worked on the button width (not sure why the other method didn't  - likely my fault): ```.my-small-btn {
    width: 120px;  /
    padding: 5px;
}  * 120 worked for the text I have */``` Just the centre alignment to sort now!

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem with the buttons? i don't see any white rectangle..?

Comment: If you mean that the buttons are vertically not aligned to their parent rows.. then the problem is that each first div in your rows has a `margin-bottom` set, which pushes them to the top.. you could just remove `class` `mb-2` from them.. then everything will look aligned..

Comment: Ahh - that's exactly what it was.  Not even sure why I had the margin bottom set at this stage, but I'm still in discovering mode with all this!  The white rectangle I'm referring to is just the text boxes on each row (when they're eventually dynamic!).  Thanks very much - I'll remove the rest of the mb-2's and all should be fine.  This is really appreciated.  Cheers.